# "Show provisioning profile disable" . How can i enable?

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded my distribution provision profile and double click to open but it is not showing like this windows

[image]

i have no idea . what's going on there . do i make any mistake ?.
 xcode version 7.3.1

Update: i am not sure is it correct or not  I found "show provisioning profile" flowing path window -> device but that is disable why?

[image]

Comment: Have you added your account in XCode? If not add the same and download all the profies.

Comment: @user2071152 could you check my update . How can I make sure have i added or not my account in Xcode ?

Comment: The way to see your provisioning profiles is in Xcode's Accounts preference pane.